# Identify this statistical filter?

Tags: computational-statistics, filter

I have a piece of code that takes a noisy data set and uses some sort of statistical filter to plot a trend line over the noisy data. The original author of the code no longer works at my job, so I can't ask him what the filter is. I've included a snippet from the code; **does any of this look familiar to anyone?** The script is written in IDL (similar to MATLAB, but a bit more arcane).

`filtered` will contain all the filtered points from the noisy dataset called `noisy`.

```
filtered = make_array(n_elements(noisy),1,/double,value=-100.0)

;define beta and sigma
beta = 0.00001
sigma = 0.005

;perform filter calculation
N = n_elements(filtered)
p_bar0 = 1
q = 1
k = p_bar0/(p_bar0 + 1)
p = k
filtered[0] = avg(noisy)


for i =1L, n-1 do begin
    m_i = exp(-1*beta)
    gamma = sqrt(sigma^2*(1-m_i^2)/(2*beta))
    phi = m_i
    eta_bar = phi*filtered(i-1)
    p_bar_i = phi*p*phi+gamma*q*gamma
    k = p_bar_i/(p_bar_i+1)
    filtered[i] = eta_bar + k*(noisy[i]-eta_bar)
    p = k
endfor
```

Comment: There are enough troubling aspects of this algorithm to suggest you might not have expressed it accurately.  The loop repeatedly computes many quantities that appear to be constant, including $m_i$, $\gamma$, and redundantly using $\phi$ for $m_i$. It also uses an undefined quantity `filtered(i)`: note that this was not initialized and so when it first occurs on the right hand side at line 4 of the loop, *it is undefined.* Although perhaps someone might be able to identify the intended algorithm despite these problems, the algorithm as written here is unclear.

Comment: @whuber ah yes, you're right, there is a line neglected that i didn't really understand that sets `filtered`, I'll update the question to include the line. This code I was handed is a bit of a mess, sorry to subject you all to it; and yes you're right that some of the variables are computed multiple times...

Comment: That helps, but there are still some suspicious elements.  For instance, do both `filtered(i-1)` and `filtered[i-1]` make sense?  Do `P` and `p` refer to the same or different objects?

Comment: Your $\bar{p}_i$ in the description doesn't seem to match the code. Are you sure you've done both correctly? Please be very careful when trying to explain what's happening. At first glance it looks like it's trying to do some kind of exponential smoothing but I have to admit I didn't look very carefully through it, since it doesn't look like it can be quite right. Any other information that might contain clues could help. You should probably tag with the relevant language name

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your continued help. I've deleted the math-version of the code since I think that was just confusing things, let's just stick with the actual code. And yes, in the arcane IDL programming language, variables are case insensitive so `P` and `p` are the same. I've fixed it anyway since it's just confusing.

Comment: @Glen_b thank you for your comments. I've just killed the math description since it seemed to be confusing things, and I tried to tag IDL but since I'm a new user I'm unable to create a new tag. I'll read up on exponential smoothing and see if I find any hits.